# Measurement of water

Tags: chicken, soup, water, broth

I've been making chicken soup for decades, but today I'm in a little bind. I have two large enough chicken thighs with bone in. How much water and broth should I use?

Comment: I'm unclear.  If you have been making soup for decades, what has changed to make this an issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that the question is unclear, there is perhaps a clear answer to this from either of the directions that I can see.

1. If you are intending on making the thighs into stock -, add your other ingredients (veges, herbs etc), if any and **cover with water**.
2. If making soup from these and adding stock + water to cook the thighs so that they are eaten as part of the dish as a whole - then again, **cover them with liquid**. How much of each component you use is up to you, but I would suggest all liquid stock for this scenario. If you have a more concentrated stock, then dilute to taste with water.